# How to not evaluate False/other values as 0

Tags: python, arrays, loops

```
def move_zeros(array):
    no_zero = [i for i in list(array) if i != int(0)]
    print(array)
    print(no_zero)

    for i in range(array.count(0)):
        no_zero.append(0)

    return no_zero
```

This is my code used for a codeacademy kata where the aim is to move all the zeros inside the list array to the front of the array. My code works for the most part however there are situations where the code gets stuck for example it sees False as zero and also values like 0.0, how do i change it so that it affects the literal number 0

EDIT: was asked for example output of the intended algorithm

```
move_zeros([false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]) 
returns[false,1,1,2,1,3,"a",0,0]
```

whereas my code returns

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `str(i) == "0"`

Comment: When I executed this script, I could see the zeros are moved to the last of the list? Is the algorithm correct? Can you add the sample input and output along with the question?

Comment: Yes @SwadhikarC that was the intended goal of the algorithm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`False` really is `0`, since `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

The value `False` is a singleton though, so you can always check `if i is False` to differentiate it from 0.

The integer `0` is also a singleton, but that's an implementation detail rather than a guarantee by the language. I'd rather not rely on that.

To exclude the `float` value `0.0` as well, you can always test the exact type: `if type(i) is int`. Subclasses of `int` will fail this test.

Comment: It would be more precise to say that `0` *may be* a singleton, but like you said, it's an implementation detail that you can't rely on, so it's better to just assume that it's  *not* a singleton in any code you write.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    result = array[:]
    # add here any false value you want
    false_values = [0, 0.0, "0", "0.0", False, ""]
    for i in result:
        if i in false_values:
            result.append(i)  # or "0" or "0.0"
            del result[result.index(i)]
    return result
```

Comment: >>> def move_zeros(array):
...     result = array[:]
...     for i in range(len(result)):
...         if result[i] == 0: # or "0" or "0.0" ...
...             del result[i]
...             result.append(0)
...     return result
...
>>> move_zeros([1, 2, 0, False, 0.0, 'string', 0, 0, 0, -1])
[1, 2, False, 'string', 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]